# android and sqlite database: can't see table

Tags: android, sqlite

hi I'm making a database that stores counter amounts. I have a save button to save a value from the counter and a view button to view a table of these values. But when I press view the screen is blank

code is below
main activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

int counter;
Button add;
Button sub;
Button save;
Button view;
TextView display;
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private String prefName = "MyPref";



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    view = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

    save.setOnClickListener(this);
    view.setOnClickListener(this);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);
    sub.setOnClickListener(this);



}

public void onClick(View arg0){
    switch(arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.button1:
        counter++;
        display.setText("Counter " + counter );
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        counter--;
        display.setText("Counter " + counter );
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        boolean diditwork = true;
        try{

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("");
            sb.append(counter);
            String count = sb.toString();
            counterdata entry = new counterdata(this);
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(count);
            entry.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            diditwork = false;
            String error = e.toString();
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Nope");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(error);
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
        }finally {
            if(diditwork){
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Hell YEa");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("Sucess");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }
        }
        break;
    case R.id.button4:
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SqlView.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

SQL view class

```
public class SqlView extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sqlview);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.databaseview);

    counterdata info = new counterdata(this);
    info.open();

    String data = info.getdata();
    info.close();

    tv.setText(data);

}

}
```

the XML for the database table

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TableLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

     <TableRow>


    </TableRow>
   </TableLayout>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/databaseview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="get database here" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

the class that handles the database

```
    public class counterdata {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_Amount = "_amount";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CounterDb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "CounterTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourhelper;
private final Context Ourcontext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                + "  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_Amount
                + "  INT)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXITS " + DATABASE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public counterdata(Context c) {
    Ourcontext = c;
}

public counterdata open() throws SQLException {
    ourhelper = new DbHelper(Ourcontext);
    ourDatabase = ourhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    ourhelper.close();
}

public void createEntry(String count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(KEY_Amount, count);
    ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}

public String getdata() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_Amount};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = " ";

    int irow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iamount = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_Amount);

    for(c.moveToFirst();!c.moveToLast();c.moveToNext())
    {
        result = result + c.getString(irow) + " " + c.getString(iamount) + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}
 }
```

any ideas?

Comment: 1. Verify that the database and table are created. 2. Verify that data makes it in there. 3. See if data is read out properly. 4. See if data read is then displayed properly. As you learn how to program, you will encounter these problems. Learning how to debug will be inevitable.

Comment: i accept @323go put log in the points he mentioned.. its easy to find the problem hence. without the log or debug result its tough to find the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont believe you have a table to begin with, because the syntax of the table isnt correct you forgot ";" at the end. it should be as the following:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
            + "  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_Amount
            + "  INT);"); // here you forget the first ';'
```

are you sure you were inserting right?!

Comment: Yeah thanks for the help and i did put in the semicolon but its still didn't work, and for the insertion I was following a video tutorial, it was weird that he didn't use any sql queries, he used that CreateEntry method i have above but I'm starting to think that doesn't work

Comment: the entry part is right.. but you need to clear and delete all your application data from the settings. so it can create a new right table. so go in your emulator to settings -> application -> yourApplicationName and click on clear data. then run the program again and insert some data. please give me a feedback :)

Comment: did just that, still didn't work, should I post my full code?

Comment: can you add this line `log.d("count", count);` under this line `String count = sb.toString();` in the `MainAcitvity` to check the value of the string `count` before adding it to the DB, and tell me the result

Comment: yeah the count is being accurately pass through, 11-18 00:52:30.577: D/count(569): 1
11-18 00:52:32.937: W/KeyCharacterMap(569): No keyboard for id 0
11-18 00:52:32.937: W/KeyCharacterMap(569): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
11-18 00:53:20.478: D/count(569): 4

Comment: I cant see any errors in Database class, neither in View Activity, try adding a value to the `result` string in counterdata class like: `String result = " anything just checking "; and check it is it available in the view class

Comment: but I logged the getdata method and check what result contained and it was blank

Comment: the value of `result = "anything just checking "` isnt saved in the db just passed in when we are getting data. I just want to check if the passing data is under process.

Comment: I figured it out, it was the for loop, instead of for(c.moveToFirst();!c.moveToLast();c.moveToNext()), in the !c.movetoLast() part it's suppose to be !c.isAfterLast(), thanks for tips on debugging, appeicate it greatly

Comment: it should be !c.isAfterLast() in the second parameter -_-